# irreducible polynomial of degree 2 or 3 without roots in an integral domain.

Tags: polynomials

It is well-known that a degree 2 or 3 polynomial over a field is reducible if and only if it has a root. 
But what about integral domains? Can we have a reducible polynomial over an integral domain having no roots in the domain?

Comment: "Can we have an **irreducible** polynomial over an integral domain having no roots in the domain?" do you mean **reducible** ?

Comment: Yes, I meant reducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example take $\mathbb{Z}$ and the polynomial $3(x^{2}+1)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$

This polynomial have no roots in $\mathbb{Z}$ but $3\cdot(x^{2}+1)$
is a factorization

Comment: Thanks. But shouldnot factorization be in lower degree than 2?

Comment: @Reader - why ? I recall that the definiton only requires that both polynimials are $\neq 0$ and that they are not invertible

Comment: A polynomial $f (x) \in F [x]$ is called irreducible over $F$ if $deg(f) > 0$ and if its only factors are $c$ and $cf(x)$, where $c \in F$, $c\neq 0$, is any non-zero constant.

Comment: @Reader - What is $F$ ?

Comment: @Reader: If you don't like the example, look at $4x^2-4x+1=(2x-1)(2x-1)$. Certainly reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, but no integer zeros.

Comment: @AndréNicolas - nice example!

Comment: Thanks. F is a field. What is definition of irreducible polynomial if F is not a field like, ring integral domain so on.

Comment: ֲ@Reader en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial#Generalization

Comment: Thanks Belgi and André Nicolas

Comment: @Reader If you have found this answer helpful, I'd appriciate it if you could please accept by pressing on the v sign near the number 1 (left from my answer)

Comment: there is no v,I would like to do it if I can find it.

Comment: I think I have clicked somewhere now, have I done it or not?

Comment: Can somebody tell me what does it means to click on V? I am new at this forum.

Comment: @Reader - A. you can accept one answer (but you can un-accpt mine and choose anothr if you want) B.  André posted a **coment** not an answer so you can not accept it unless he posts an answer (which I think he should!)

Comment: @ Belgi Oh I see.